# How to get angle between two lines in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, measurement

I am working on a logo in which I have to calculate what angle the cut is. Is there a tool in illustrator that lets us calculate the angle between 2 red lines?
[image: find the angle between 2 red lines]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable Smart Guides <kbd>U</kbd> and use the Rotate tool <kbd>R</kbd> to measure an angle.

1. With the Direct Selection tool <kbd>A</kbd>, select a line segment.
2. Press <kbd>R</kbd> to engage the Rotate tool
3. Click on the corner anchor to set it as the rotation centre
4. Click and drag the line and rotate until it snaps to the other anchor. The Angle is displayed.

Finally, undo the changes using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

Example

[image]

Comment: This is great. thank you, one mistake happened while I was rotating, it rotated by canvas and now I cannot set it back to way it was. I can use the trackpad to rotate it but it still have some difference.

Comment: @localhost I don't recommend using a trackpad with Illustrator - too inaccurate. Use a mouse. To reset canvas rotation, click View > Reset Rotate View.

Answer (score 2):

One way to determine the angle between 2 lines is to select each line separately and note it's angle from the Transform Panel.

Simply calculate the difference between the 2 angles.

[image]

Comment: so I did the maths one was 97.416 and other was 4.442. so is it correct to say 97.4-4.44 = 92.96 ?

Comment: yes, that is pretty much it- it can be confirmed with @Billy Kerr's answer